# A differential equation of second order with polynomial coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a second order differential equation with polynomial coefficient as follows:

$$x^2(x^2-1)y''-x(x^2+1)y'+(x^2+1)y  = 0$$

If I have one answer I can clearly obtain the other one. Can you please help me to guess the answer?

Comment: What about $y=c_1 x$ ?

Comment: It seems that $c_1x$ works, but how did you guess that?

Comment: $y''=0$ gives an immediate solution since then $xy'=y$. The second one is more complex. Cheers :-)

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: You are very welcome ! Let me know the second solution, please. Cheers :-)